# Android TextView padding

Tags: android, textview, design

В textview текст по умолчаниию не растягивается на весь view, присутствуют отступы. Есть ли какая то зависимость этих отступов от размера текста?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка такая

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3 товара на сумму"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/summ"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ruble"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:text="ОФОРМИТЬ"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:background="@color/lavka_main_red" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ruble"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/summ" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: в теме поумолчанию , возможно, у TextView заданы отступы, или фон типа `nine-patch`, у которого выставлены отступы.

Comment: я имею в виду отступы не вокруг TextView, а внутри. Стандартные. Когда я пытаюсь в RelativeLayout выравнять какой нибудь элемент по тексту, то вижу не четкую привязку этого элемента к дну или верху теста, а к дну или верху TextView, то есть внешний вид у меня "пляшет".

Comment: Как насчет показать разметку и скриншоты? Как вы видите, совершенно непонятно, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: в данном случае опора "2 продукта на сумму", по низу выравнивается сумма и изображение рубля. И из за отступов этти view идут не по нижней линии текста, а "пляшут". То же самое и в списке продуктов со знаком рубля. Мне необходимо добиться "линейности", чтобы всё ыло ровно